# treeview loses checked values when click event is occured

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have asp.net Treeview which is out side update panel of asp.net page,when i click on btnGet (which is also exists outside the update panel) it loses the checked value of treeview control. but it persist the values of other controls which are placed in update panel.

to handle the control outside the updatepanel, I have used javascript.(functionality like enable or disable & validation & its text)

How to persist treeview's checked values?

any help would be greatful!

```
<asp:Panel ID="treePanel" runat="server">
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr><td>
     <asp:TreeView ID="treeViewS" runat="server" ShowCheckBoxes="All" ShowLines="True" >
     </asp:TreeView>
</td></tr>
</table>
</asp:Panel>
<table width="980" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center">
<tr><td>
   <asp:Button ID="btnGet" runat="server" Text="Get" ValidationGroup="GetValidationGrp"
                                                OnClick="btnGet_Click" OnClientClick="if (startGet()) return false;" />
</td></tr>
<table>
```

Comment: When are you binding data to the treeview?

Comment: nodes are populated dyanamically

Comment: Are you populating them on each postback? If you're repopulating them on postback you'll reset the checked values.

Comment: populating tree on  page_load, but not on each post back, cause its degrading performance

Comment: Ok, that was just a possible obvious cause. Could you post some code?

Comment: just not getting why only treeview which is not placed in update panel not persisitng data? if other control can? just cause I m handling it from client side(is it can be a prob)?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use jstree (http://www.jstree.com/) and jQuery instead of ASP.NET updatepanel and treeview. If you want to continue with that ASP.NET, please paste some code.